# How to restore mutable bitmap state after call to Canvas.drawText

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a common bitmap used in multiple cases as a marker for Google Maps. 
Each time I use this bitmap, I draw some text over it. Sometimes that leads to OutOfMemory exceptions. I would like to know if it's possible to keep one static mutable bitmap in memory and just provide a copy with text overlayed to Maps.

Currently, I have a reference to an immutable bitmap, from which I create mutable copies. 
Is it's possible to somehow get to its original state, without text?

Current code:

```
public static Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String text) {
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    Bitmap mutableBitmap = null;
    try {
        mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        canvas.save();
        // new antialised Paint
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        // text size in pixels
        paint.setTextSize((int) (BITMAP_TEXT_SIZE * scale));
        // text shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.GRAY);

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - convertDpToPixel(BITMAP_TEXT_OFFSET);
        int y = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    } catch(Throwable t) {

    }
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Do you need it in Bitmap form or would simply a custom View with drawing ability work?  You could most likely copy that same code in the `View#draw()` method of `View` and it would still work the same.

Comment: I can't use custom views with Google Maps V2